# InsertBefore not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tired **insertBefore** property, it throws script error that

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

Below code i used.

```
            parent = document.getElementById(parentid[i]);
            before = document.getElementById(beforeid[i]);
            appenchild1 = document.getElementById(beforeid[i]);
            appenchild2 = document.getElementById(appenchild2id[i]);
            newnode = document.createElement("span");
            newnode.className = "verticalHparent" + btncls[i];
            newnode.style.display = "inherit";
            parent.insertBefore(newnode, before);
```

Error throwing on insertBefore method, anything wrong?

Comment: show html structure

Comment: hard to tell if you did not post your html structure but you can check my answer for working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty explanatory; *The `before` node should be child of `parent` node on your code.*

Here is a working example (look at the html structure):

```html
<div id = "parent">

    <div id = "child_1">child1</div>
    
</div>

<button onclick="createNewElement()">Create New Child</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function createNewElement(){

        var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
        var before = document.getElementById("child_0");
        
        var newnode = document.createElement("span");
        newnode.className = "verticalHparent";
        newnode.style.display = "inherit";
        newnode.innerHTML = "child2";
        parent.insertBefore(newnode, before);
    
        
    }
    
 
</script>
```